# While loop won't break in R

Tags: r, while-loop, break

```
invest <- 10000 
p_value <- runif(1,0,1)

while (invest != 1000000 | invest != 0) {

    p <- rbinom(1,1,p_value)

    if (p == 0) {

    invest <- invest - 1000

    } else {

    invest <- invest + 1000

    } 

    print(invest)

}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the while loop will not break when reaching 1000000 or 0 and essentially runs infinitely (the print feature is only there to witness the resulting values while testing).  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: use `cat("\n", invest)` inside any loop to know where you're at. Maybe `<=` instead of `!=`.

Comment: I suspect it is your OR statement at the top. at invest == 1000000 it returns (FALSE|TRUE) which is equal to TRUE

Comment: What @Rob said. You need `&` instead of `|`. `invest` must be different from both 0 and 1000000 to run the loop. However, you should follow @RLave suggestion and constrain by inequalities (which is more robust and don't suffer floating point issues).

Comment: Thank you RLave, Rob and nicola.  It did work on my end though I'm confused as to why the OR logic operator also wouldn't apply considering a single value couldn't satisfy as both 1000000 and 0 at the same time .  I appreciate the tips regarding robustness and versatility.

Comment: Use a not vectorized `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
invest <- 10000 
p_value <- runif(1, 0, 1)
while(0 < invest && invest < 1000000){
    if(rbinom(1, 1, p_value) == 0)
        invest <- invest - 1000
    else
        invest <- invest + 1000
    cat("invest:", invest, fill=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn how logical operators work.

What you wrote is: `invest is not 1000000 OR invest is not 0`. That is always true. There is no value for which this could not be true.

1. invest is 0 => 0 is not 1000000 => true
2. invest is 1000000 => 1000000 is not 0 => true
3. invest is any other value => not 1000000 and not 0 => true